# Flatten a dataset in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, flatten, tensor, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to convert a dataset in TensorFlow to have several single-valued tensors. The dataset currently looks like this:

```
[12 43 64 34 45 2 13 54] [34 65 34 67 87 12 23 43] [23 53 23 1 5] ...
```

After the transformation it should look like this:

```
[12] [43] [64] [34] [45] [2] [13] [54] [34] [65] [34] [67] [87] [12] ...
```

My initial idea was using `flat_map` on the data set and then converting each tensor to a list of tensors using `reshape` and `unstack`:

```
output_labels = self.dataset.flat_map(convert_labels)

...

def convert_labels(tensor):
    id_list = tf.unstack(tf.reshape(tensor, [-1, 1]))
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(id_list)
```

However the shape of each tensor is only partially known (i.e. `(?, 1)`) which is why the unstack operation fails. Is there any way to still "concat" the different tensors without explicitly iterating over them?

Answer (score 4):

Your solution is very close, but [`Dataset.flat_map()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#flat_map) takes a function that returns a `tf.data.Dataset` object, rather than a list of tensors. Fortunately, the [`Dataset.from_tensor_slices()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_tensor_slices) method works for exactly your use case, because it can split a tensor into a variable number of elements:

```
output_labels = self.dataset.flat_map(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices)
```

Note that the [`tf.contrib.data.unbatch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/unbatch) transformation implements the same functionality, and has a slightly more efficient implementation in the current master branch of TensorFlow (will be included in the 1.9 release):

```
output_labels = self.dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.unbatch())
```