# Flattening tuple of images in tensorflow dataset

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a dataset of triplet images that I'm reading from tfrecords, that I've converted to a dataset using the following code

```
    def parse_dataset(record):
        def convert_raw_to_image_tensor(raw):
            raw = tf.io.decode_base64(raw)
            image_shape = tf.stack([299, 299, 3])
            decoded = tf.io.decode_image(raw, channels=3, 
                                dtype=tf.uint8, expand_animations=False)
            decoded = tf.cast(decoded, tf.float32)
            decoded = tf.reshape(decoded, image_shape)
            decoded = tf.math.divide(decoded, 255.)
            return decoded

        features = {
            'n': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            'p': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            'q': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
        }
        sample = tf.io.parse_single_example(record, features)
        neg_image = sample['n']
        pos_image = sample['p']
        query_image = sample['q']

        neg_decoded = convert_raw_to_image_tensor(neg_image)
        pos_decoded = convert_raw_to_image_tensor(pos_image)
        query_decoded = convert_raw_to_image_tensor(query_image)
        return (neg_decoded, pos_decoded, query_decoded)

    record_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames=path_dataset, num_parallel_reads=4)
    record_dataset = record_dataset.map(parse_dataset)
```

The shape of this resulting dataset is

```
<MapDataset shapes: ((299, 299, 3), (299, 299, 3), (299, 299, 3)), types: (tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32)>
```

which I think means that each entry contains 3 images (which I confirmed by iterating through the dataset and printing the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd elements). I want to flatten this, so I get a dataset that doesn't contain any tuples but just a flat list of images. I've tried using flat_map but that just converts the images to (299, 3) and I've tried iterating through the dataset, appending each image to a list, then calling convert_to_tensor_slices but that's really inefficient.

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49960875/flatten-a-dataset-in-tensorflow) but it didn't seem to help.

Btw this is the flat_map code I tried

```
record_dataset = record_dataset.flat_map(lambda *x: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x))
```

and the resulting dataset has this shape

```
<FlatMapDataset shapes: ((299, 3), (299, 3), (299, 3)), types: (tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32)>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are just unpacking the tuple wrongly.

this ought to do it:

```py
def flatten(*x):
  return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([i for i in x])

flattened = record_dataset.flat_map(flatten)
```

so that:

```py
for i in flattened:
  print(i.shape)
```

gives:

```
(299, 299, 3)
(299, 299, 3)
(299, 299, 3)
(299, 299, 3)
...
```

as expected